creating C# classes by parsing jsondoc JSON file?
I am consuming an REST API (Contrast Security ) which unfortunately for me, does not provide Swagger documentation. It does provide JSONDoc, and I'm able to extract what looks like a JSONDoc JSON file (accessible only to a logged in user).  The provided .NET REST client lacks many methods that exist in the JSONDoc, some of which I need.  In order to extend the client properly, I would like to extract the method names and paths and other useful information from the JSONDoc JSON file.  The most straightforward way would seem to be to make some C# classes and use Newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize it and then inspect the deserialized object for the names, paths, etc that I need.
I am not sure if it is legal for me to post the JSONDoc JSON file where it could be viewed by non-customers of Contrast Security.
I tried using the online tool Json2csharp. It generated syntactically correct C# that even looks close to useful, but it is referencing several classes that it did not generate. On closer inspection, it seems that some of the classes it generated are named after the name property in the JSON, when actually those classes are really different instances of the same class.
Any pointers?

Absent a [mcve] there's no way we can answer this question.  If https://json2csharp.com/ is not working for you, you could try any of the other tools from How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string.  You could also load free-form JSON via JToken.Parse() as shown in this answer to Deserializing JSON to .NET object using Newtonsoft (or LINQ to JSON maybe?).
